# Shell script: how can i get the second element separated by comma

Tags: shell, awk, sh

How can I calculate the number of occurences of the second value e.g.:'Rv1408' ? i want to get and calculate the total number of occurrences of the 2nd element in each line.<.br>

file.txt:

```
Rv0729,Rv1408,Rv1408  
Rv0162c,Rv0761,Rv1862,Rv3086  
Rv2790c,Rv1408
Rv2fd90c,Rv1408
Rv1862,Rv3086
Rvsf62,Rv3086
```

i tried(doesnt work)
input:

```
awk ' { tot[$0]++ } END { for (i in tot) print tot[i],i } ' m.txt | sort | cut --delimiter=',' --fields=1
```

Expected Output:

```
total no of occurences: 
Rv1408: 3
Rv0761:1
Rv3086: 2
```

idk why i cannot get the second element even if i type fields=2

Comment: Inside your awk block, loop over all fields and increment a count whenever an element equals the second field. It is not clear from your question, whether the output, if there is no other field of the same value, should be 0 or 1 (i.e. whether or not you include field number 2 in your count). Basically, your question is a pure awk problem. I suggest that you drop the _shell_ and _sh_ tags and add instead an _awk_ tag.

Comment: i changed the codes, idk why i cannot get the second element even if i type fields=2

Comment: but it can get the first vaule , cannot get the second one

Comment: You are calculating the value of `tot` over **all** rows. `tot["foo"]` is the number of times the word "foo" is the first field. Why do you want to sum up things over all lines, when you need instead one sum for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it easier by passing the -F comma field separator.

Like this:

```
awk -F, '{map[$2]++} END { for (key in map) { print key, map[key] } }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> idk why i cannot get the second element even if i type fields=2

When you are providing more than 1 argument to `print` GNU `AWK` does join that arguments using *output field separator* (`OFS`) which by default is space, yet you informed `cut` that it should treat `,` as delimiter.

If you must use `awk` output piped into `cut` then make sure that output field separator of `awk` and delimiter of `cut` is same, you have basically three options,

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}END{print 11,22,33}' emptyfile.txt | cut --delimiter=',' --fields=2
awk 'END{print 11,22,33}' emptyfile.txt | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=2
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}END{print 11,22,33}' emptyfile.txt | cut --fields=2
```

all of them give same output

```
22
```

Explanation: 1st option is to explicitly set `OFS` and `--delimiter` to same character in both commands (`,` in example), 2nd option is to set `--delimiter` to default value of `OFS` which is space, 3rd option is to set `OFS` to default value of `--delimiter` which is TAB character.

**Warning** in most cases there is no need to pipe `awk` output to `cut` as task might be done entirely in `awk`.